# MySQL - Update field in insert into query from select query

Tags: mysql

I have following two tables `A` and `B`.

I would like to insert records from table `A` into table `B` but with new `orderNum` value as and when new records are being added into table `B`.

I have following query but not working as expected.

```
INSERT INTO B (refId, userId, orderNum)
SELECT id, '1', (SELECT count(refId) + 1 FROM B WHERE userId = 1) as orderNum
FROM A 
WHERE is_mendatory IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY is_mendatory ASC
```

Let say I have 3 records exist in table `B` and using `SELECT` query I am going to insert 5 more records. So those new 5 records should be inserted with orderNum from 4,5,6,7,8.

But currently it only sets 4 as `orderNum` for new 5 records.

Can anybody suggest something on this?

Edit:

I am getting on 4 in `orderNum` field for new 5 records.

Comment: what output you are getting in this query ?

Comment: @YoYo, I am getting on 4 in orderNum field for new 5 records.

Answer (score 0):

Create a before insert trigger,count the rows in B for each INSERT,store the number in a variable,update the table with the number of rows.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER orderNum_after_insert
BEFORE INSERT
   ON B FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN

SET @orderNo:=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B);
SET NEW.orderNum=@orderNo;

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Can't I do with Query written above with some modification?

Comment: @NullPointer The problem is in your query namely a query is a transaction,so your count will only count the rows before the insert ,you want a count after each row inserting.